# PHP str_replace not working on Azure php7

Tags: php, string, azure, php-7

Is there any possible cause that block this `str_replace()` to work?
PHP 7 working fine for everything else on Azure app services, nothing else in the PHP script.

```
<?php
$testo="cinque";
str_replace("q", "K", $testo);
die($testo);
?>
```

It returns

> cinque

I'm becoming crazy because of this, thanks!

Comment: Variables aren't passed to `str_replace` by reference. It _returns_ a string with the replacement made.

Comment: Just check [the examples in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-examples).

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the results of the function to a variable, it doesn't replace the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $testo = "cinque";
  $testo = str_replace("q", "K", $testo);
  die($testo);
?>
```

Comment: Don't just post code, include an explanation of how the code fixes the problem in the question.